# Class 'Stripe\StripeCharge' not found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've had a look at a few answer to this quesition on Stack Overflow, but there solutions didnt work for me. Im receiving the following error whilst testing the Stripe API

> Class 'Stripe\StripeCharge' not found

This is the code that I am using:

require_once('app/init.php');

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    try {

        \Stripe\StripeCharge::create(array(
            "amount" => 2000,
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "card" => "$token",
            "description" => $Email
            ));

    } catch(Stripe_CardError $e){

        //Error Payment

    }
}

echo $_POST['stripeToken'];

/* Stripe Vairables */
$stripe = [
    'publishable' => 'hidden',
    'private' => 'hidden'
];
```

I didn't use composer to pull this as it works with the include of the "init" file (supposedly). Any help would be great!

Comment: Simple mistake - The array was set below everything else *FACEPALM*

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the class is `\Stripe\Charge`, not `\Stripe\StripeCharge`. You can see an example of a charge creation request in the API documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge

Also, the `card` parameter was renamed to `source` in the [2015-02-18](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2015-02-18) API version.

Another problem is that you assign the `$stripe` array with your API keys at the end. You need to assign it before you can use it in the call to `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey()`.

There were a few other minor mistakes. Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
require_once('app/init.php');

/* Stripe variables */
$stripe = [
    'publishable' => 'hidden',
    'private' => 'hidden'
];

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

    try {

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 2000,
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => $email
        ));

        // echo $charge->id;

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

        // Card error

    }
}
```